# How can I make the CPU to switch from "minimum processor state" to "maximum processor state" much much faster?

Tags: windows, cpu, power-management

In Windows 7, in "Power options", the "minimum processor state" is set to 5%. Because of this, some programs are really slow. For example when I compile source code, the compilation time (Delphi 7) is 5.2 seconds. If I set minimum processor state to 100% the compilation time is 3 sec. However, I have a Intel CPU so when minimum processor state is set to 100% the CPU overheats and laptop's cooler starts to "scream".

How can I make the CPU to switch from "minimum processor state" to "maximum processor state" much much faster?

Comment: This is not an Intel problem as AMD does the same thing thus should show the same behavior, I think it differs more based on the processor you have. I had a T7500 and it didn't seem like a problem to me, I now have a i7 720QM and that doesn't show the problem either... Btw, thank you as I discovered that my minimum processor state was set to 5% instead of 0%. (I don't think they wrote it in such way that 0% slows down, if so I can still increase)

Comment: But my Delphi never acted like that on my old AMD CPU.

Comment: Well, older processors work differently as they have no power management...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(partial) Solution 1.
Setting the "minimum processor state" to 80% decreases the time to 4 seconds. But the CPU still overheats (80% is pretty much). This is a good lesson (learned the hard way) about choosing CPU manufacturer for laptops :(

Update/(partial) Solution 2.
To fix this Intel/Windows bug, create several power profiles and manually switch between them.

Update/(full) Solution 3:
I have uninstalled Windows 64 bits and installed Windows 32. The problem is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

There will always be some delay in ramping up the CPU performance.  What you gain in power savings and not overheating you lose in the transition from a lower cpu speed to a faster one.

Instead of running at 100% minimum all the time you could go to something like 70%.  This would likely be a fair compromise where overheating wouldn't be too much of an issue and you would get a faster compile. It's also nice to see someone's still using Delphi besides myself.  ;)

Comment: There's quite a few of us Delphi users out there still. Plenty at StackOverflow.